# Find an example of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Find an example of a sequence of integrable random variables $\lbrace X_n,n\geq1 \rbrace$ that has the following properties,

1. $E[X_{n+1}\mid X_n]=X_n$ for every $n\geq 1$ but
2. $E[X_{n+1}\mid F_n\phantom{.}]\neq X_n$ for every $n\geq 2$,

where $F_n=\sigma(X_j;1\leq j \leq n)$.

How do we construct such sequence?

Comment: What does the notation $\sigma\left(X_j;1\le j\le n\right)$ mean?

Comment: @Shash smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ (underlying probability space) s.t. the $X_j$ are measurable for $j=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Reformulate it as $X_{n+1} = X_n + \epsilon_n$ where $\mathsf E[\epsilon_n|X_n] = 0$ and $\mathsf E[\epsilon_n|\mathscr F_n] \neq 0$. For example, try to make $\epsilon_n$ a function of $X_{n-1}$ such that it still has mean zero given $X_n$.

Comment: Perhaps I have a misconception: Does not $F_n$ include $X_n$?

Comment: @Stef: it does, but it also contains more. Imagine that you'd have $E[X_{n+1}|X_n,\ldots,X_1]=\bar{X}$. That, is your expectation of the $n+1$th value would be the mean of the past values you know.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Yes, thanks! So, if I understand correctly we are looking for a case where knowing less (i.e. only $X_n$) means that we can infer $E[X_{n+1}|X_n]=X_n$ but knowing more. (i.e $\mathcal F_n$) then we can infer something else (more specific, probably), i.e. $E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n]\neq X_n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ be a sequence of iid random variables such that $\mathbb{E}Y_1=0$. Consider

$$X_n := Y_n + Y_{n-1}.$$